# EC2 public instance not accessible

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing this issue as I am new to AWS EC2. I have setup an instance and ssh working perfect. I installed httpd, mysql, php and httpd and mysql services running fine.

I can't access EC2 public DNS in a browser. I already added a rule for HTTP with port 80 but still not working. What can be the other reasons?

Comment: 1) Did you start httpd? is it up and running 2) Are you using public IP while typing the url?

Comment: Yes httpd running. i am trying with both public IP and EC2 public DNS as well.

Comment: Why down rating? That is really bad.

Comment: What is the message you are getting in browser when you try to access?

Comment: When you SSH to the instance and then curl localhost, does it return your web page? If it does, then you likely have a firewall (Security Group) issue. Temporarily enable inbound port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 in the SG to validate this.

Comment: First, login to the instance via SSH and try `curl http://localhost`. This will check that the web server is working. Next, try accessing the web server via its **Public IP address**. This will check the Security Group rules. Let us know what problems you encounter. When you say "EC2 public DNS", are you referring to the one displayed in the console (eg `ec2-54-251-107-67.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`)?

Comment: SSH working fine. I see "This site can't be reached". Yes i have tried public provided by EC@ instance and public DNS like John has mentioned. ALl return the same error. I have already added HTTP rule in SG. But still i am not able to access it via browser.

Answer (score 0):

For this trouble shoot like below :

Step 1) ssh to instance and stop the iptables if it is running.

Step2)  if above step not resolves the issue, please post the log out put of browser. is it 404 error or DNS not found or 403 something like that. Then I can assist you.

Comment: I have stopped iptables already but still not working. The browser shows this message "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: This site can’t be reached

IP refused to connect.